# What is the Conjugate of $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}-7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having problems finding the conjugate of $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}-7}$

The answer I get is as follows: ${-4\sqrt{3}-7}$

However the answer given is ${-4\sqrt{3}+7}$

Here are my workings out...
$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}-7} * \frac{4\sqrt{3}+7}{4\sqrt{3}+7} = \frac{4\sqrt{3}+7}{-1} = {-4\sqrt{3}-7}$

I'd appreciate any guidance on where I've gone wrong.

Comment: How did you get $-1$ for the denominator?  And what is your definition of "conjugate"?

Comment: In beginning you say the answer you got is $-4(\sqrt{3}-7)$ but when you show your working you get $-4(\sqrt{3}+7)$

Comment: Aren't you forgetting a square root for that $\;7\;$ ?

Comment: @kingW3 :-| That's what I was thinking...

Comment: Wait:$$(\sqrt3-7)(\sqrt3+7)=3-49=-46\implies \frac1{4(\sqrt3)}=\frac{\sqrt3+7}{-46}\ldots$$ How is there nothing wrong with his work?? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @DonAntonio Whoops, you saw nothing

Comment: I've cleaned this up a bit now as there were some unnecessary brackets in there that weren't in the original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Hemmed Yes...brackets/parentheses in mathematics can make a **huge** difference...!

Comment: What a nasty problem. The student gets caught up in all of the detail of rationalizing the denominator and forgets to take the conjugate when he or she is almost finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after all the changes:

$$(4\sqrt3-7)(4\sqrt3+7)=48-49=-1$$

and **then indeed**:

$$\frac1{4\sqrt3-7}=-\left(4\sqrt3+7\right)=-4\sqrt3-7$$

and yes: the conjugate is $\;\frac1{4\sqrt3+7}\;$ , and what you say is the answer given is neither the conjugate nor the product of the original expression by its conjugate.

**Added following an idea by projectilemotion:** Perhaps the idea is **first** to rationalize the expression **and then** to find its conjugate:

$$\text{Rationalizing:}\;\;\frac1{4\sqrt3-7}\cdot\frac{4\sqrt3+7}{4\sqrt3+7}=-4\sqrt3-7$$

and now the rightmost expression's conjugate indeed is: $\;-4\sqrt3\color{Red}+7\;$ .....tadaaah!

It's hard to tell what they meant without knowing a priori their definitions... BTW, in this case and **for me**, the conjugate could as well be $\;4\sqrt3-7=-7+4\sqrt3\;$ ...Funny.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the conjugate I get ends with -7 but in the example given in the quiz the conjugate is actually +7.

Comment: @Hemmed The conjugate **is** $\;\frac1{4\sqrt3+7}\;$, but where you wrote "my working" you are *actually* multiplying the original expression by its conjugate. Two different things...

Comment: Yeah, I've got pretty confused the full example is given here: [link](http://www.mathopolis.com/questions/q.php?id=3195)

Is there a language thing where I'm missing what the question is asking for?

Comment: @DonAntonio Interestingly, when rationalizing the denominator of the conjugate $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}+7}$, the answer $-4\sqrt{3}+7$ is given. Perhaps that is what the question is referring to.

Comment: @projectilemotion That seems to be a reasonable assumption. I couldn't tell without knowing the *proper definition* the use.

Comment: @projectilemotion I think this might be it. Basically the question i'm given is 'What is the conjugate of...' but then the answer is as follows:

The conjugate of (4√3 - 7) is (4√3 + 7), but this is not the answer! 

[image of full text](http://www.mathopolis.com/questions/latex/1/f/b72fad27ccce19b5b2f26e050a794b1.gif)

Unfortunately I'm still now sure how to get to -4(sqrt 3)+7 as the conjugate, as I get -4(sqrt 3)-7 as it.

Comment: Yes sorry, there's a follow up bit which is:

Now we can find the conjugate by changing the sign in the middle:
[image](http://www.mathopolis.com/questions/latex/b/c/58b7d909fd494b513dcc64acdd31e21.gif)

but I get the conjugate as (4√3 - 7)

Comment: @Hemmed Read the stuff I just added to my answer. It fits what you say the answer and it is most probably they way they defined in your school the term "conjugate": after first rationalizing and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, sorry - this is the definition I knew. This is really dumb, but when you rationalize how do you get to −4√3−7 ?

Comment: @DonAntonio That's a good guess. Or maybe the expected answer was $\frac{1}{-4\sqrt{3}-7}\,$.

Comment: @Hemmed I think we already went over this: $\;(4\sqrt3-7)(4\sqrt3+7)=16\cdot3-7\cdot7=48-49=-1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand that part, but, and this is probably me being stupid, how does $\frac{4\sqrt{3}+7}{-1}$ become $-4\sqrt{3}-7$

Comment: @Hemmed ?? Well, that is basic mathematics: $$\;-a-b=-(a+b)=\frac{-(a+b)}1=\frac{a+b}{-1}=\ldots etc.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I had a brain fail :(